# How to calculate the mean of one variable (sales) in respect to another (id)?

Tags: r, merge, data.table, mean, lapply

I have a data set that looks like this:

```
id          .........   date             sales
19164958    .........   2001-09-01  .... 30
39578413    .........   2001-09-01  .... 75.6
```

There are about 65k observations in the data set. The data is structured in 4 columns: id (which are non-consecutive in the range of 10 to 80 millions), churn, date and sales. It describes the spending of all customers for about 3/4 of a year.

Now I shall calculate the average spending of each customer. I have been given this code:

```
aggr.data <- merge(data[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = c("id"),.SDcols = c("sales")], 
                   data[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = c("id"),.SDcols = c("sales")], 
                   c("id", "sales"))
```

Now I have the problem that r does not know .SD.
Can anybody please tell me what I have to change to receive the results. Or does anybody know what other commands I can use to get the average spendings of each id?

Thank you for your help

```
dput(head(tel))
structure(list(id = c(19164958L, 39578413L, 43061957L, 51326773L, 
54271247L, 70765025L), churn = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), date = structure(c(11566, 
11566, 11566, 11566, 11566, 11566), class = "Date"), sales = structure(c(522L, 
849L, 649L, 649L, 522L, 649L), .Label = c("100", "100.2", "100.4", 
"100.6", "100.8", "101", "101.2", "101.4", "101.6", "101.8", 
"102", "102.4", "102.8", "103", "103.2", "103.4", "103.6", "103.8", 
"104", "104.2", "104.4", "104.8", "105", "105.2", "105.6", "105.8", 
"106", "106.2", "106.4", "106.6", "106.8", "107", "107.2", "107.4", 
"107.6", "108", "108.2", "108.4", "108.6", "108.8", "109", "109.2", 
"109.4", "109.6", "109.8", "110", "110.2", "110.4", "110.8", 
"111", "111.2", "111.4", "111.6", "111.8", "112", "112.4", "112.6", 
"112.8", "113.2", "113.4", "113.6", "114", "114.2", "114.4", 
"114.8", "115.2", "115.6", "116", "116.2", "116.4", "116.8", 
"117", "117.2", "117.4", "117.6", "117.8", "118", "118.4", "118.8", 
"119.2", "119.6", "119.8", "120", "120.4", "120.6", "120.8", 
"121.2", "121.4", "121.6", "121.8", "122", "122.2", "122.4", 
"122.8", "123", "123.2", "123.6", "123.8", "124", "124.4", "124.8", 
"125", "125.2", "125.4", "125.6", "125.8", "126", "126.4", "126.8", 
"127", "127.2", "127.6", "127.8", "128", "128.4", "128.8", "129", 
"129.2", "129.4", "129.6", "130", "130.2", "130.4", "130.8", 
"131.2", "131.4", "131.6", "131.8", "132", "132.4", "132.8", 
"133.2", "133.4", "133.6", "133.8", "134", "134.4", "134.8", 
"135", "135.2", "135.6", "135.8", "136", "136.2", "136.4", "136.8", 
"137.2", "137.6", "138", "138.4", "138.6", "138.8", "139.2", 
"139.6", "140", "140.2", "140.4", "140.8", "141.2", "141.4", 
"141.6", "142", "142.2", "142.4", "142.6", "142.8", "143.2", 
"143.6", "144", "144.2", "144.4", "144.6", "144.8", "145.2", 
"145.4", "145.6", "146", "146.4", "146.6", "146.8", "147.2", 
"147.6", "147.8", "148", "148.2", "148.4", "148.6", "148.8", 
"149.2", "149.6", "149.8", "150", "150.2", "150.4", "150.8", 
"151", "151.2", "151.6", "152", "152.4", "152.8", "153", "153.2", 
"153.6", "154", "154.4", "154.6", "154.8", "155.2", "155.6", 
"155.8", "156", "156.2", "156.4", "156.6", "156.8", "157.2", 
"157.4", "157.6", "157.8", "158", "158.4", "158.8", "159.2", 
"159.4", "159.6", "160", "160.2", "160.4", "160.8", "161.2", 
"161.4", "161.6", "162", "162.4", "162.8", "163", "163.2", "163.6", 
"163.8", "164", "164.4", "164.8", "165", "165.2", "165.6", "166", 
"166.4", "166.8", "167.2", "167.4", "167.6", "168", "168.4", 
"168.8", "169.2", "169.6", "170", "170.2", "170.4", "170.8", 
"171", "171.2", "171.6", "172", "172.4", "172.8", "173.2", "173.6", 
"173.8", "174", "174.4", "174.8", "175.2", "175.6", "175.8", 
"176.4", "176.8", "177", "177.2", "177.6", "178", "178.2", "178.4", 
"178.8", "179.2", "179.4", "179.6", "179.8", "180", "180.4", 
"180.8", "181", "181.2", "181.6", "182", "182.2", "182.4", "182.8", 
"183.2", "183.6", "183.8", "184", "184.4", "184.8", "185.2", 
"185.6", "186", "186.4", "187.2", "187.4", "187.6", "187.8", 
"188", "188.4", "188.8", "189.2", "189.6", "189.8", "190", "190.4", 
"190.8", "191.6", "192", "192.4", "192.8", "193.2", "193.6", 
"194", "194.4", "194.8", "195.2", "195.6", "196.4", "196.8", 
"197.2", "197.6", "197.8", "198", "198.2", "198.4", "198.8", 
"199.2", "199.6", "200", "200.4", "200.8", "201.2", "201.6", 
"202", "202.4", "202.8", "203.6", "204", "204.4", "204.8", "205.6", 
"206", "206.4", "206.6", "206.8", "207.2", "207.6", "208", "208.4", 
"208.8", "209.2", "209.6", "209.8", "210", "210.4", "210.6", 
"210.8", "211.2", "211.6", "212.8", "213.2", "213.6", "214", 
"214.4", "214.8", "215.2", "215.4", "216", "216.2", "216.8", 
"217", "217.2", "217.6", "218.4", "218.8", "219.2", "219.6", 
"220", "221", "221.2", "221.6", "221.8", "222", "222.4", "223.2", 
"223.6", "224.4", "224.8", "225.2", "225.6", "226", "226.2", 
"226.4", "226.6", "227.2", "227.8", "228", "228.4", "228.8", 
"229.2", "229.6", "229.8", "230", "230.4", "230.8", "231.6", 
"232.2", "232.4", "232.8", "233.2", "233.6", "234.4", "234.8", 
"235.6", "235.8", "236", "237.2", "237.4", "237.6", "238", "239.2", 
"240.4", "240.8", "241.2", "241.6", "242", "242.4", "243.4", 
"243.6", "244.6", "245.2", "245.6", "246", "246.4", "247.2", 
"248", "249.6", "250", "250.4", "250.8", "251.2", "251.6", "252.8", 
"254.4", "254.8", "255.2", "255.4", "255.6", "256", "256.4", 
"256.8", "257.2", "257.6", "258.8", "259.2", "260", "261.6", 
"262", "262.4", "262.8", "263.2", "263.6", "264", "264.4", "264.8", 
"266", "266.8", "267.2", "267.6", "268.4", "270", "270.2", "270.4", 
"271", "271.2", "271.6", "272.4", "272.8", "273.2", "274", "274.4", 
"275.2", "275.6", "276", "276.8", "278.8", "279.2", "279.6", 
"280", "281.6", "282", "282.6", "283.2", "284.8", "285.6", "287.2", 
"289.6", "290.4", "291.2", "293.2", "295.2", "296", "296.8", 
"298", "299", "30", "30.2", "30.4", "30.6", "30.8", "300.8", 
"301.2", "301.6", "302.8", "303.6", "304", "304.4", "305.2", 
"306", "306.4", "307.2", "308.8", "309.2", "31", "31.2", "31.4", 
"31.6", "31.8", "310.8", "313.2", "313.6", "314", "315", "315.6", 
"316", "316.4", "316.8", "317", "318.4", "319.6", "32", "32.2", 
"32.4", "32.6", "32.8", "322", "324.8", "326.4", "326.8", "327.2", 
"328.4", "329.2", "329.6", "33", "33.2", "33.4", "33.6", "33.8", 
"331.6", "332.4", "332.8", "334", "338.4", "338.6", "339.2", 
"34", "34.2", "34.4", "34.6", "34.8", "340", "341.2", "342", 
"342.4", "347.2", "347.6", "35", "35.2", "35.4", "35.6", "35.8", 
"350", "352.8", "353.2", "354", "354.8", "355.6", "357.6", "36", 
"36.2", "36.4", "36.6", "36.8", "360.8", "361.6", "362", "362.4", 
"363.6", "365.6", "367.6", "368", "368.4", "369.6", "37", "37.2", 
"37.4", "37.6", "37.8", "371.6", "372.4", "375.6", "377", "38", 
"38.2", "38.4", "38.6", "38.8", "382.6", "384.8", "385.2", "387.2", 
"388", "388.4", "39", "39.2", "39.4", "39.6", "39.8", "390.4", 
"391.2", "397.6", "399.6", "40", "40.2", "40.4", "40.6", "40.8", 
"405.2", "408.8", "41", "41.2", "41.4", "41.6", "41.8", "411.6", 
"414.4", "419.2", "42", "42.2", "42.4", "42.6", "42.8", "43", 
"43.2", "43.4", "43.6", "43.8", "430.2", "432.4", "437.2", "438", 
"439.6", "44", "44.2", "44.4", "44.6", "44.8", "444.8", "45", 
"45.2", "45.4", "45.6", "45.8", "450", "454", "455.6", "46", 
"46.2", "46.4", "46.6", "46.8", "47", "47.2", "47.4", "47.6", 
"47.8", "473.2", "474", "475.6", "48", "48.2", "48.4", "48.6", 
"48.8", "482.4", "49", "49.2", "49.4", "49.6", "49.8", "50", 
"50.2", "50.4", "50.6", "50.8", "500", "503.2", "51", "51.2", 
"51.4", "51.6", "51.8", "52", "52.2", "52.4", "52.6", "52.8", 
"521.6", "53", "53.2", "53.4", "53.6", "53.8", "54", "54.2", 
"54.4", "54.6", "54.8", "55", "55.2", "55.4", "55.6", "55.8", 
"550", "56", "56.2", "56.4", "56.6", "56.8", "57", "57.2", "57.4", 
"57.6", "57.8", "58", "58.2", "58.4", "58.6", "58.8", "59", "59.2", 
"59.4", "59.6", "59.8", "60", "60.2", "60.4", "60.6", "60.8", 
"61", "61.2", "61.4", "61.6", "61.8", "62", "62.2", "62.4", "62.6", 
"62.8", "63", "63.2", "63.4", "63.6", "63.8", "64", "64.2", "64.4", 
"64.6", "64.8", "65", "65.2", "65.4", "65.6", "65.8", "66", "66.2", 
"66.4", "66.6", "66.8", "67", "67.2", "67.4", "67.6", "67.8", 
"68", "68.2", "68.4", "68.6", "68.8", "69", "69.2", "69.4", "69.6", 
"69.8", "70", "70.2", "70.4", "70.6", "70.8", "71", "71.2", "71.4", 
"71.6", "71.8", "72", "72.2", "72.4", "72.6", "72.8", "73", "73.2", 
"73.4", "73.6", "73.8", "74", "74.2", "74.4", "74.6", "74.8", 
"75", "75.2", "75.4", "75.6", "75.8", "76", "76.2", "76.4", "76.6", 
"76.8", "77", "77.2", "77.4", "77.6", "77.8", "78", "78.2", "78.4", 
"78.6", "78.8", "79", "79.2", "79.4", "79.6", "79.8", "80", "80.2", 
"80.4", "80.6", "80.8", "81", "81.2", "81.4", "81.6", "81.8", 
"82", "82.2", "82.4", "82.6", "82.8", "83", "83.2", "83.4", "83.6", 
"83.8", "84", "84.2", "84.4", "84.6", "84.8", "85", "85.2", "85.4", 
"85.6", "85.8", "86", "86.4", "86.6", "86.8", "87", "87.2", "87.6", 
"87.8", "88", "88.2", "88.4", "88.6", "88.8", "89", "89.2", "89.6", 
"89.8", "90", "90.2", "90.4", "90.6", "90.8", "91", "91.2", "91.4", 
"91.6", "91.8", "92", "92.2", "92.4", "92.6", "92.8", "93", "93.2", 
"93.4", "93.6", "93.8", "94", "94.2", "94.4", "94.6", "94.8", 
"95", "95.2", "95.4", "95.6", "95.8", "96", "96.2", "96.4", "96.6", 
"96.8", "97", "97.2", "97.4", "97.6", "97.8", "98", "98.2", "98.4", 
"98.6", "98.8", "99", "99.2", "99.4", "99.6", "99.8"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("id", 
"churn", "date", "sales"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: If you are asking a language specific question, say r, it makes sense to add a language tag - you'll get help quicker

Answer (score 2):

```
mydf$sales <- as.numeric(as.character(mydf$sales))
```

Using base R

```
 tapply(mydf$sales,mydf$id,mean)
```

where mydf is your dataframe

Using data.table package

```
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(mydf)
DT[,mean(sales),by=id]
```

Using plyr package

```
library(plyr)
ddply(mydf,.(id),meansales=mean(sales))
```

Comment: +1, but why `keyby` instead of a normal `by`? did OP ask for sorted/keyed results?

Comment: Thanks. Updated now!. Not sure

Comment: using tapply returns the error message:
argument is neither numerical nor boolean

Comment: Did you change `mydf` with the name of your dataframe?, For example using mtcars data, this is `tapply(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$cyl,mean)`

Comment: Yes. That's what it looks like when I use your first answer: mclv <- function(data) {

  data <- as.data.table(data)
  aggr.data <- merge(data[, tapply(data$sales,data$id,mean)], 
                     data[, tapply(data$sales,data$id,mean)], 
                     c("id", "sales"))
  return(aggr.data)
}

Comment: You don't need to use `tapply` if you use the `data.table`.

Comment: @Metrics FYI, it only *looked* like the OP was using a data.table and that the sales column was numeric; see the dput now in the question. :)